# Is that possible to use the states in Redux across different browsers for Reactivity?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reactive-programming

Does anyone know if that could be possible to use Redux across different browsers on one machine to implement some kind of reactivity?
For instance, I've got a todo lists which is state controlled, could these state be shared with several browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you talk about several browsers, you will need to add a backend to the mix, so the backend is the source of truth.

You could setup a simple WebSocket / socket.io server with Node.js. On your clients, send the state to the server when it changes and broadcast it to the rest of connect clients. Here's a nice article in about this, using Redux in the server, that may give you some hints:

https://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html

Comment: By different browsers, I meant on the same machine, so it might be a bit overkill to add another layer on the server to handle redux states?

Comment: It's irrelevant if they're on the same machine or oceans apart. Each browser is a new, different connection to the server. The only way to communicate between them is with a server. The server code could be around 20 lines of node.js, don't fear. ;) Read the tutorial it's very good indeed.

Comment: You're definitively right, in fact as I'm a total newbie to Redux, I wasn't sure that this technology was or not able to communicate its content through WebSockets or something like that. Yes, I'm reading the tutorial, It looks to be the solution.